# Is a bank statement needed to apply for a German visa if I have an invitation?

Tags: schengen, applications, schengen-visas, invitation-letters

I want to know that will it still be necessary for me to sent my bank statement to the Germany embassy for schengen visa , whilst i received a invatation from the one inviting me from Germany ?

Comment: An invitation is trivial to come by, but offers no guarantees that the invited person will return home...

Answer (score 5):

The bank statements have several purposes. One of them is to show that you have a stable job in your home country. This makes you appear more likely to return home at the end of the visa, and less likely to become an illegal immigrant. This is still necessary if you have an invitation.

Comment: what if im still a student and im just invited by a friend who is working in Germany?

Comment: You have to show that you will go back to your home country. The bank statements are just *one* part of that. It will also help if you have to go home for the final part of your degree. It will hurt if you have just finished your degree and look for a job.